# GeoDatabase to KML Conversion

Tags: kml, google-earth, ms-access

I have some US Forest Service GIS data which is a set of roads and trails an Accesss Database, also commonly referred to a GeoDatabase or a Personal GeoDatabase. Its a standard Access MDB File. From a little browsing it appeears to be binary blobs (proprietary?) surround by a bunch of descriptive fields.

You can download the same data here: http://www.fs.fed.us/r6/data-library/gis/mtbaker-snoqualmie/ It's Transportation.zip

I woudl like to convert this data to KML so I can open it in Google Earth. I've spent the better part of a day searching to no avail.

Anyone have a script or a pointer to a better place to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a comment than an answer....

Converted it with FME workbench (safesoftware) is a 15mb.kmz

can add styles to the layers too.

the data was a personal geodatabase (.mdb).

[image]

Comment: Sent you email. Did you use FME by Safe? Is that correct.
https://www.safe.com/fme/

Comment: will send it tomorrow as not at work till then.

Comment: in theory QGIS http://www.qgis.org/en/site/ can open the personal geodatabase and then you can export to kml from qgis

Answer (score 2):

- To export all data within the mdb file, first add them to a mxd (map) and then save the mxd and use "[Map to kml](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Map_To_KML/00120000004p000000/)" tool.
- To export only one feature class use "[Layer to Kml](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004n000000)" tool.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned. I do not own ARCGIS.

Comment: Why did you tag with 'arcgis' if you don’t have ArcGIS?

Comment: Because that is where it came from...